# How to get an subset of properties given as list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i need map object data with array

```
const data = [
              {name:"John", age:"22", weight:"60", height:"180cm"},
              {name:"Emma",age:"25",weight:"55",height:"160cm"}
             ]

const key =  ["name", "weight", "height"]
```

i need result like this

```
const result = [
                {name:"John", weight:"60", height:"180cm"},
                {name:"Emma", weight:"55",height:"160cm"}
               ]
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: if I get it correctly all you want is to remove propery name age?

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just `map` over each of the objects, and use `Object.fromEntries` to create a new object with the given keys:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "John", age: "22", weight: "60", height: "180cm" },
  { name: "Emma", age: "25", weight: "55", height: "160cm" }
]
const keys = ["name", "weight", "height"]

const res = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]])))
console.log(res)
```

It would be even better to use `reduce` instead of two loops, albeit less readable:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "John", age: "22", weight: "60", height: "180cm" },
  { name: "Emma", age: "25", weight: "55", height: "160cm" }
]
const keys = ["name", "weight", "height"]

const res = data.map(o => keys.reduce((a, k) => (a[k] = o[k], a), {}))
console.log(res)
```